# How many shards for maximizing writes per second for Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read in the documentation that writes per second are a maximum of 10,000 for Cloud Firestore. But if a collection has sequential values ​​with an index, there are only 500 writes per second allowed.

> "Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values ​​in an indexed field: 500 per second"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas?hl=en

In order to increase the writes per second, a "shard" field should be implemented. The number of writes of 500 is then multiplied by the number of shards.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/shard-timestamp?hl=en

**My question is: Does that mean that a number of 20 shards will increase my writes per second to the maximum of 10,000? And more shards are superfluous?**

Further shards would only make sense if I wanted to increase the writes per second for a single document, as I understand it. For example, for a counter that is then divided into several documents, in order to avoid the write limit of one second per document. (This scenario is not relevant for my purpose)

I think it wouldn't be much of a hassle for me to implement 20 shards from the start, even though I may never need them. Just to make sure I won't have any problems with it in the future as the number of users increases.

I know that one downside would be more complicated queries. But I think, that I could easily avoid this in my App because of how my data is structured.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked has this example of determining the necessary number of shards:

> After some research, you determine that the app will receive between 1,000 and 1,500 instrument updates per second. This surpasses the 500 writes per second allowed for collections containing documents with indexed timestamp fields. To increase the write throughput, you need 3 shard values, `MAX_INSTRUMENT_UPDATES/500 = 3`.

So it indeed seems that you can simply divide your necessary throughput by 500 (the maximum number of writes per shard) to get the number of shard values you'll need.

Don't forget that you'll need to also [update the index definitions](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/shard-timestamp#update_index_definitions) to drop the existing indexes on your sequential (in the example: timestamp) field, and add composite indexes on that field and the shard field. The 500/second throughput limit comes from the write speed of individual indexes, so it's actually having multiple composite indexes that increases the throughput.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. So does that mean that more than 20 shards are unnecessary because with 20 shards I would already achieve the maximum writes of 10,000 per second?